# Physical interpretation of single layer potential in the plane

Tags: electrostatics, potential, charge

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary $\partial\Omega$. The single layer potential with charge density $f$ sitting on $\partial\Omega$ is defined by $u(z)=\displaystyle\int_{\partial\Omega}f(w)\ln|z-w|ds_w.$ What is a physical interpretation of the single-layer potential in the plane? (For $\mathbb{R}^3$ this matter is discussed e.g [here](http://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/potphys.pdf))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the line integral which gives you the electric potential in two dimensions due to a charge distribution of one or more closed loops, i.e. closed charged wires.

The logarithm is coming from the solution of laplace equation in two dimensions, replacing the $\frac{1}{|\vec{x} - \vec{x}'|}$ of three dimensions, and $f(w)$ is just the charge density along the wire (loop). For $ds_w$, this is just the line element, which is the differential length along the charged wire (loop).

I think a notationally more transparent expression would be 
$$
\phi(\vec{x}) = \sum_i\oint_{\mathcal{C}_i}dl' \,\rho(\vec{x}') \text{ln }|\vec{x}  - \vec{x}'| 
$$